# Masking multiple instances of sensitive data in logs of Azure Monitor Application Insights for Java

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry, azure-monitoring

In trying to implement masking of sensitive data in logs sent to Azure Application Insights, with official documentation:
[Masking sensitive data in log message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-telemetry-processors-examples#masking-sensitive-data-in-log-message)

Only single instance of sensitive data is shown to be masked. I would like to mask variable number of instances of sensitive data in my logs. Let's say my sensitive data is userId: "A12345678Y" and "B23456789Z"

I would like to mask all the userIds in the log: "User A12345678Y has friended User B23456789Z, and User A12345678Y has 20 mutual friends with User B23456789Z". There is a variable number of userIds, meaning there could be tens of userIds per log.

I have tried masking instances of userId by adding the rule: `".*(?<redactedUserId>[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z]).*"` twice in the `"rules"` JSON config.

JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "preview": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "type": "log",
        "body": {
          "toAttributes": {
            "rules": [
              ".*(?<redactedUserId>[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z]).*",
              ".*(?<redactedUserId>[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z]).*"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "attribute",
        "actions": [
          {
            "key": "redactedUserId",
            "action": "delete"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2 instances of userId has been deleted. 
Pre Masked:
`"User A12345678Y has friended User B23456789Z, and User A12345678Y has 20 mutual friends with User B23456789Z"`

Post Masked:
`"User A12345678Y has friended User B23456789Z, and User {redactedUserId} has 20 mutual friends with User {redactedUserId}"`

What if I have 50 instances of userId? or 70? I would like to mask all of them. Hardcoding 50 lines of the rule seems unwise.

How should I implement such that variable number of instances of userId is masked?

**Edit with solution:**

I have finally solved this as well as replacing {redactedUserId} to any message I want to be shown in my logs.

I did it by:

1. 1st Processor is a log processor converting an entire log message
   that contains userId into a single attribute named "LogMessage"
2. 2nd Processor is an attribute processor that searches for regex
   pattern which I inputted to be userId, and replaces it to be
   "**Censored Message Here**". The value for the attribute
   "LogMessage" is now a censored log message.
3. 3rd Processor is a log processor converting the "{LogMessage}"
   attribute in the logs back to its value. So rather than displaying
   "{LogMessage}", my logs will display as "User **Censored Message
   Here** has friended User...
4. 4th Processor is an attribute processor that cleans up and deletes
   the "LogMessage" attribute from the log custom properties.

JSON:

```
"processors": [
        {
          "type": "log",
          "body": {
            "toAttributes": {
              "rules": [
                "(?<LogMessage>.*[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z].*)"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "attribute",
          "actions": [
            {
              "key": "LogMessage",
              "pattern": "[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z]",
              "replace": "**Censored Message Here**",
              "action": "mask"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "log",
          "body": {
            "fromAttributes": [
              "LogMessage"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "attribute",
          "actions": [
            {
              "key": "LogMessage",
              "action": "delete"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A change was done in Application Insights 3.4.16 to allow you to mask every userId from one rule. Have you tried with the 3.4.16 version?

Comment: Hi, thanks for this insight. I was previously using 3.4.15 and have just updated to 3.4.16.

Comment: However, I cannot find any documentation on how to implement this multi-handling from one rule. I am trying the rule:
"rules": [
              ".*(?<redactedUserId>[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z]).*"
            ]

but only the last instance of it is masked.
How should I configure the rule to handle multiple matching?

Comment: Ok I managed to figure it out. Thanks a lot! Adding a "+" at the end worked as it checks for 1 or more instances of the sensitive information.
"rules": [ "(?<redactedUserId>[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z])+" ]

Answer (score 1):

> How should I implement such that variable number of instances of userId is masked?

You can achieve this by using a custom processor or filter in your Java application before sending the logs to Azure Application Insights.

- Custom log processor that scans log messages for sensitive data and replaces them with placeholders. You can use regular expressions to find and mask userIds.

Use a loop or a similar mechanism to iterate through the log message.

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LogMasker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String logMessage = "User A12345678Y has friended User B23456789Z, and User A12345678Y has 20 mutual friends with User B23456789Z";
        
        // Construct a regular expression pattern to match userIds
        Pattern userIdPattern = Pattern.compile("[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z]");
        Matcher matcher = userIdPattern.matcher(logMessage);

        StringBuffer maskedLog = new StringBuffer();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            // Replace each userId with a placeholder
            matcher.appendReplacement(maskedLog, "{redactedUserId}");
        }
        matcher.appendTail(maskedLog);

        // Output the masked log message
        System.out.println(maskedLog.toString());
    }
}
```

And also you can use a custom log appender or a filter.

**Custom Log4j Appender:**

```java
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class CustomLogMaskerAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomLogMaskerAppender.class);

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        String logMessage = event.getRenderedMessage();

        // Construct a regular expression pattern to match userIds
        String pattern = "[A|B][0-9]{8}[Y|Z]";

        // Replace all matches with {redactedUserId}
        String maskedLogMessage = logMessage.replaceAll(pattern, "{redactedUserId}");

        // Log the masked message
        event.setRenderedMessage(maskedLogMessage);
        super.append(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Cleanup, if necessary
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

- It will log messages with sensitive data masking using the custom Log4j appender while sending telemetry data to Azure Application Insights.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have successfully implemented this feature by using updated version of application insights 3.4.16. :)