# How to enable TelemetryClient.trackTrace() logs to be handled by LogProcessor of Azure Monitor Application Insights for Java?

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I am using Azure Monitor Application Insights for Java and have noticed that my logs that are published to application insights using @slf4j log.info() are processed by LogProcessor and AttributeProcessor (successfully masked sensitive data in logs). However, when using TelemetryClient.trackTrace() to publish logs, the log processor appears to not affect these logs.

I have a
[Working LogProcessor and AttributeProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098276/masking-multiple-instances-of-sensitive-data-in-logs-of-azure-monitor-applicatio) already.

However, these only work on @slf4j log.info() logs and not TelemetryClient.trackTrace() logs.
TelemetryClient.trackTrace() logs were sent to application insights but did not have their sensitive data masked.

[TelemetryClient documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.azure/applicationinsights-core/2.1.0/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/TelemetryClient.html)

How should I go about to make TelemetryClient.trackTrace() publish logs that are processed by Azure Monitor Application Insights for Java?